# Web GUI for Snort + ModSecurity

Tags: firewalls, snort, monitoring, mod-security

I'm trying to find a suitable (or easily modifiable) web GUI for snort + modsecurity logs. As far as I know, Splunk can do that by installing the snort and modsecurity plugins. Is there any other option?

It does not have to be ready at the get go, I'm fine with a little modification here and there.

Comment: You can use Jwall Auditviewer http://jwall.org/web/audit/viewer.jsp

Answer (score 3):

Those logs are all created in standard syslog format so any log aggregation solution will allow you to view and search the logs. There are plenty of options such as you mentioned but also proprietary like LogRhythm, ArcSight, LogLogic and others or open source like Alienware (OSSIM), OSSEC, Snare etc

There's also a GUI using BASE for Snort.